# How to handle optional Realm sync?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have an app with local/offline Realm files/databases. I would like to add the option to log in to sync data across devices, and I figured Realm Object Server would be great for this. I know that when a user logs in, I will need to write a migration from a local realm to a synced realm. What do I do if a user decides to logout? What do I do if a user never logs in in the first place? Do I need to have two paths in my code (everywhere) to choose whether it should use the local or synced realm?

Answer (score 0):

I use a `RealmProvider` class to get the realm instance.

```
class RealmProvider {
    class func realm() -> Realm {
        if let _ = NSClassFromString("XCTest") {
            return try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(fileURL: nil, inMemoryIdentifier: "test", syncConfiguration: nil, encryptionKey: nil, readOnly: false, schemaVersion: 0, migrationBlock: nil, deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true, objectTypes: nil))
        } else {
            let user = getUser()
            guard let loggedInUser = user else {
                do {
                    return try Realm()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                return try! Realm()
            }
            // open up synced url to the username.
            if let user = SyncUser.current {
                let syncServerURL = URL(string: "realm://realm.myapp.com/~/\(loggedInUser.username.md5())")!
                let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: syncServerURL))

                // Open the remote Realm
                return try! Realm(configuration: config)
            } else {
                // login first.
                let serverURL = URL(string: "http://realm.myapp.com")!
                let token = getToken()

                let customCredentials = SyncCredentials(customToken: token, provider: Provider("custom/myAuth"))
                //
                SyncUser.logIn(with: customCredentials,
                               server: serverURL) { user, _ in
                                if let user = user {
                                    // can now open a synchronized Realm with this user
                                    // Open Realm
                                    let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
                                        syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://realm.myapp.com/~/\(loggedInUser.username.md5())")!)
                                    )
                                    _ = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
                                }
                }
            }
            return try! Realm()
        }
    }
}
```

To answer your question,

> What do I do if a user decides to logout?

The RealmProvider will give you a local realm file.

> What do I do if a user never logs in in the first place? 
>   The data will still be stored in a local realm file, once the user logs in, you can open up a synced realm and run the migration.

PS: There is one catch, if the synced realm is being opened the first time, it will still return the local realm file. :/

Comment: If a synced user logs out would I need to reverse migrate from a synced realm to a local realm? Would I need to copy all the data again?

Comment: yes, if a user logs out, the provider will give you a local realm file. It wont have any synced data in it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't that sound terrible? I'd need to constantly migrate back and forth if the user logs in or out. It's essentially maintaining two databases based on state

Comment: I take it the data stored in a synced realm is specific to a logged in user. If the user logs out, default settings are to be used right? Not sure about your use-case though.

Comment: Yes not only is it specific to the user, it’s private data as well that cannot be shared with others.